# Using WiX Burn to Select Which .msi's to Install/Modify/Uninstall

Tags: wix, installation, burn

I was looking at the solution presented here:

[WiX Burn - Determine what items are already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917287/wix-burn-determine-what-items-are-already-installed)

But I don't see how this could work for a "modify" Burn screen (when somebody decides to remove a certain .msi).

Looking at the Burn .log when the uninstall/modify page shows up (I called my variables that describe whether a check box is checked, 'Checkbox1' through 'Checkbox6'):

```
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Checkbox1' to value '1'
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Checkbox2' to value '1'
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Checkbox3' to value '1'
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Checkbox4' to value '1'
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Checkbox5' to value '1'
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Checkbox6' to value '1'
```

(etc.)

```
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i100: Detect begin, 3 packages
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i000: Setting string variable 'NETFRAMEWORK40' to value '1'
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i052: Condition 'NETFRAMEWORK40' evaluates to true.
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i101: Detected package: NetFx40Redist, state: Present, cached: None
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i101: Detected package: Setup, state: Present, cached: Complete
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i101: Detected package: Setup1, state: Present, cached: Complete
[171C:1034][2013-04-23T11:49:24]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
```

So, this makes me wonder, where are the results of "Detect" for the various .msi's stored?  Why can't they be stored into my own variable, 'Checkbox1', that I later use to set the value of a checkbox, whether it's checked or not?

As a more fundamental question, isn't this usage pattern of Burn one of the key usage patterns that should be well supported in the standard UI...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control whether a package should be installed by setting it's `InstallCondition` attribute. For example, if `Checkbox1` was determined whether `Msi1` should be installed, you're chain could have:

```
<MsiPackage Id='Msi1' InstallCondition='Checkbox1' SourceFile='path\to\msi1.msi' />
```

You'd probably want to define your `Checkbox1` variable such that it persisted it's value:

```
<Variable Name='Checkbox1` Value='1' Persisted='yes' />
```

Note: This by default assumes `Msi1` should be installed because the value is defaulted to `'1'`.

The only thing left is to tie your `Checkbox1` to UI in the wixstdba. You can do this by overriding the Theme file and adding checkboxes to the `Options` page that use `Checkbox1` as the `@Id` of the control.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you!  There was a really nice UI I started with at http://wixextba.codeplex.com/ - I'm just adding a little change here or there.