# Installer to execute multiple .msi files

Tags: c#, installation, wix, sharpdevelop

I have developed several applications and their executable are in .msi format.

Now I need to develop a single installer which when installed should install all of my developed application( 8 to 10 msi files)

Is there any way to achieve this using Wix Setup Project or something else.

Comment: The title is a little misleading. Sounds like you want them to be installed concurrently (which is not possible, AFAIK but not sure). But the question body only says you need one installer for several msi (that could run sequentially, right?)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing out i"ll change the title

Comment: What I want is the user needs to execute only one setup files and all the msi files packaged into gets installed by that

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727057/how-to-add-an-msi-file-to-my-installer

Answer (score 1):

Use Wix's bundle, and chain multiple

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/chain.html